# Are there any other measures of complexity for a continuous map than topological entropy?

Tags: general-topology, entropy

Let $X$ be a compact topological space and $T\colon X\to X$ be continuous.

In order to say something about the complexity of $(X,T)$ there is of course the notion of topological entropy of $T$, either defined by Adler et al. or by Bowen.

Are there any other concepts for complexity? Maybe you have a hint or a literature hint.

Thank you!